# Как поместить button в input

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Необходимо создать счетчик товаров для добавления в корзину, сделал так

```js
up.onclick = () => {
  numericUpDown.value = (isNaN(numericUpDown.value)) ? 1 : +numericUpDown.value + 1;
};
down.onclick = () => {
  numericUpDown.value = (numericUpDown.value) > 0 ? +numericUpDown.value - 1 : 0;
}
```

```css
.test {
  color: #484E56;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 129px;
  height: 48px;
  background: rgba(193, 217, 94, 0.22);
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.test:focus {
  outline: 0;
  outline-offset: 0;
}

.minus {
  background: url("img/minus.png");
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.plus {
  background: url("img/plus.png");
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter">
  <input id="numericUpDown" type="number" value="1" class="test" onkeypress="return false" />
  <button id="down" class="minus"></button>
  <button id="up" class="plus"></button>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что не могу "засунуть" кнопки плюс и минус в input. Новичок в верстке.
Сейчас это выглядит как-то так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: подсказка, position:absolute)

Comment: absolute при изменении разрешения слезал, но подошло position: relative. Спасибо)

Comment: У вас ошибка в коде - у `<button>` должен быть закрывающий тег. (тут в вопросе исправил)

Answer (score 4):

Вот такой вариант

```js
up.onclick = () => {
  numericUpDown.value = (isNaN(numericUpDown.value)) ? 1 : +numericUpDown.value + 1;
};
down.onclick = () => {
  numericUpDown.value = (numericUpDown.value) > 0 ? +numericUpDown.value - 1 : 0;
}
```

```css
.counter {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.counter input,
.counter button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.counter .test {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 45px;
  background: #f2f6de;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.counter button {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background: #dce7a4;
  color: #1e8448;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.counter .minus {
  left: 0;
}

.counter .plus {
  right: 0;
}

/* Код чтобы убрать стрелки у стандартного input number */

.counter > input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.counter > input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  margin: 0;
}

.counter > input[type="number"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter" style="width: 150px">
  <input id="numericUpDown" type="number" value="1" class="test" onkeypress="return false" />
  <button id="down" class="minus">-</button>
  <button id="up" class="plus">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть вариант позиционировать отрицательными значениями относительно родительского элемента.

```css
.range {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
}

.number {
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.up,
.down {
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.up {
  left: 4px;
  top: -28px;
}

.down {
  top: -28px;
  right: -36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="range">
  <input type="number" class="number">
  <button class="up">+</button>
  <button class="down">-</button>
</div>
```

Выходит такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]